# PictureBox.Paint event keeps firing

Tags: c#, winforms, events, graphics

My PictureBox.Paint event keeps firing, and I don't know what's causing it.

```
    private void GamePictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawMap(e.Graphics);
    }

    public void DrawMap(Graphics g)
    {
        lock (MainBlock)
        {
            for (int RectsX = 0; RectsX < GamePictureBox.Width - 1; RectsX += (int)MainBlock.RectSize.X)
                for (int RectsY = 0; RectsY < GamePictureBox.Height - 1; RectsY += (int)MainBlock.RectSize.Y)
                    g.DrawRectangle(MainBlock.BlockColor, RectsX, RectsY, MainBlock.RectSize.X, MainBlock.RectSize.Y);
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                GamePictureBox.Invalidate();
                GamePictureBox.Update();
            }));
        }
    }
```

GamePictureBox.Width and GamePictureBox.Height = 601;
MainBlock.RectSize.X and MainBlock.RectSize.Y = 60.1f;
The main problem is that after the 2 for loops inside DrawMap, finish, the Paint event calls DrawMap again! This keeps happening (infinite loop) and it's kinda annoying. I've tried debugging but my debugging skills only took me far enough to know that the cause of the problem was the Paint event.

The event is called NOWHERE other than the Paint event.

Comment: You asked for it, calling Invalidate() in a Paint event handler.  Can be moderately useful in a game app, although using Invoke() is a pretty drastic mistake since that turns painting into a high priority activity that prevents any user input to be processed first.  Best to stop shooting your leg off when you don't like to hop around on one foot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Invalidate() forces a new Paint, what triggers infinite loop.

In the Paint event, you should only draw on the graphics, i.e. no Invoke().

Comment: It worked now although I have tried commenting that Invoke out before.

Comment: Can't edit the comment above so:
The Paint event still activates if I move the windows form around, is that normal or is something inside my code still triggering it (which I highly doubt)?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the MSDN documentation on Control.Update:
"*Causes the control to redraw the invalidated regions within its client area.*"

Quoting the MSDN documentation on the Control.Paint event:
"*Occurs when the control is redrawn.*"

So when you call `GamePictureBox.Update();` you trigger a new Paint event.
Remove the whole section with the Invalidate + Update, that's intended when something has changed that requires new rendering (in your scenario, if MainBlock.BlockColor is changed, for example, you'll want to trigger a new event).